# Ruby Rails change all the fields using form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I change all count value at same time, currently i have to change each of them individually.

```
<% @book.each do |book| %>
    <%= form_for(book) do |f| %>
        <%= f.number_field :count %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

lets say my current value 2,5,1 and when i change :count field to 3, result should be like 3,3,3 to all. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more specific.
if you need to update a column for all rows use this

```
Book.update_all(:count, 3)
```

or on book controller

```
Book.update_all(:count, params[:book][:count])
```

Comment: use this    `Book.update_all("count = ?", params[:book][:count])`